# Best way to send images from URL to python POST requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am working on a script which will take a product link from a user and fetch that from information as a JSON body and extract some necessary information like

```py
title = data['screens'][0]['meta']['default_value']['title']
desc  = data['screens'][0]['meta']['default_value']['description']
price  = data['screens'][0]['meta']['default_value']['price']
collection_id  = data['screens'][0]['meta']['default_value']['collection']['cc_id']
shipping  = data['screens'][0]['meta']['default_value']['mailing_details']
img_url = data['screens'][0]['meta']['default_value']['photos'][0]['image_url']
```

```
title -> Baby Toys product number - 1
desc  -> This is description of the product
price -> 52
collection_id -> 24
Shipping -> Free
photo_1 -> http://cdn.test.com/media/213234/cover.jpg
```

Now I want to send a post request to another api using this information

```py
data = {
    'mailing_details': shipping,
    'multi_quantities': 'true',
    'abcpay':'false',
    'price': price,
    'description':desc,
    'title':title,
    'meetup':'false',
    'condition':'2',
    'mailing':'true',
    'collection_id':collection_id
    }
```

UPLOAD API

```py
files = {'photo_1': ('img_url', 'image/jpeg')}
response = requests.request("POST", url_and,data=data,files=files,headers=headers)
```

Now what I want to do is bind that image from img_url to files dict and send files as a POST requests.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide `url_and`

Comment: It's a product upload api  
```
https://api.test.com/api/3.0/listings/
```

Comment: Oh my bad I thought you where scraping a website